# How can I check how many people have a role in a specific discord server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to see how many people in my server have the `Helper` role.

My code so far:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
  let server = "746326753466908742"
  var yourRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Helper");
  var members = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == yourRole)).map(member => member.user.tag);
  let sunucuTanıtım = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('IECode Sunucu:')
  .setDescription(`Helperları Aşşağıdaki Listeden Görebilirsiniz.\n\Sunucudaki Helper Listesi: ${members}`)
  .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())

if (message.content === `${prefix}server`)
message.channel.send(sunucuTanıtım)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Role` has a property called `members`, which is a `Collection`. Therefore, you can use:

```js
console.log(Role.members.cache.size)
// --> 50 (depending on how many people have the role)
```

Comment: how can i set this for 1 discord server

Comment: You need to get the `Role` object from your guild. You already have it as the variable `yourRole`. Doing `yourRole.members.cache.size` should work.

Comment: i want when someone use it in another server it will show my server's Helper role stats

Comment: Try to use: `client.guilds.cache.get("YourServerID").roles.cache.get("YourRoleID").members.cache.size`.