# How to check how many people have a role using discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to see how many members have a certain role in my server. To do so I am using the code:

```
const bots = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Bots");
console.log(bots.members.cache.size);
```

which was the solution provided in this question: [How can I check how many people have a role in a specific discord server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538208/how-can-i-check-how-many-people-have-a-role-in-a-specific-discord-server)

However, I keep getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Role#members` itself returns a `Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>`, so just use

```js
bots.members.size
```

and it should work.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if this worked for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if this helps, you are able to set the value of "bots.members.size" and compare it to a number to test for an exact number of users with a role.

```
const bots = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Bots");
if (bots.members.size == 1){
    message.channel.send("One person has this role")
}
```